# Preventing other network users installing Remote Desktop 3 via the AppStore

Tags: remote-desktop

I have installed Remote Desktop 3 (purchased from the AppStore) on my administrators machine. However, if one of our employees installs Remote Desktop 3 themselves onto their machine on the network via the App Store, how I can prevent them also accessing all the machines on our network?

Or will I have to disable admin access to everyone's machines other than mine on the network?

Answer (score 4):

How are they supposed to know the login credentials for the other machines? And if they *do know* the credentials, they could probably do whatever they want with ssh, vnc, afp, etc… anyway, so no need to prohibit ARD, really.

To make it more precise: if you cannot trust your users not to spy on each other, don´t let them know each others passwords!